# Selecting css file dynamically by clicking on the button in FLEX 3

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex3, styles, stylesheet

I need to create an application in which we are changing the style of the application that is theme of the application based on the button click.

I have download the theme that all contains different CSS file. I need to dynamically declare the CSS for the application to apply that theme.

[image]

I have file name Theme1.css, Theme2.css, Theme3.css, Theme4.css, Theme5.css.

when I click on the Theme 1 Button then I need to apply Theme1.css file as source of style. similar like that when I click on the Theme 2 Button then I need to apply Theme2.css file as source of style.

Note : css file contains Style for both application and component of the Application.

Have a Nice DAY....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use the facility within eclipse/flex builder to compile the CSS into SWF so that the styles can be changed at runtime.

You would also have to maintain the instance variable of the current theme id.

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public function switchTheme(theme:int):void {
    StyleManager.unloadStyleDeclarations("assets/styles/Theme"+currentTheme+".swf");
    StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("assets/styles/Theme"+theme+".swf");
    this.currentTheme = theme;
}
```

You would then assign the click handlers for each button to the switchTheme function - passing the theme id as a parameter.

Comment: Hi Roy,

Thanks for the answer.
But still facing the problem. when i call the method unloadStyleDeclaration it gives me an exception. So in short, it is not working.

Comment: @SagarRawal, if you let me know the exception, maybe I can help.

Comment: I am getting the error: "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." on the 900 line of StyleManagerImpl.as and i am using FLEX SDK 3.4....

Comment: You did initialize the variable currentTheme somewhere above the function, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to loop all control one by one and set theme on control.
for Eg.
    If you set default theme RED and button is red then you change theme to Blue then you set button color to blue using looping of control.
May be this help to you....

Please ask me if you not getting what i am saying...

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Manoj,

It is not like that I need to change the the theme when user clicks on the button. First understand the Problem and then answer.

Comment: Hi Sagar Rawal,
My solution is also help to you.
Please try to loop all control and then ask me if any problem.

Comment: It also helps me... Good solution Manoj Savalia

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile your CSS files as SWF. You can right-click the CSS files in Flash Builder's explorer window and select "Compile CSS to SWF" from the menu.

Then you use the `loadStyleDeclarations()` method from `StyleManager` to load the SWF file with your CSS info.

The previous step will only add the new styles to your style subsystem. If you want to clear the old styles, you need the `unloadStyleDeclarations()` method first.

If you unload the currently active CSS declarations, use `false` as the second parameter so `StyleManager` does not invalidate the styles and rebuilds the style declaration chains/cache for the components on stage. This is not only be slow, but will also result on a screen refresh with the default styles before applying the new styles.

You could have something similar to this, and call `applyTheme('url/to/theme.swf')` with the appropriate URL whenever you want to change the theme:

```
private var currentThemeURL:String = 'themes/default.swf';

public function applyTheme(themeURL:String):void
{
    StyleManager.unloadStyleDeclarations(currentThemeURL, false);

    StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations(themeURL);
    currentTheme = themeURL;
}
```